# Java: Is this a correct way to get the current time as a Calendar object in a particular time zone?

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

I know there are other similar questions to this, but I came up with my own way of getting the current time in a specific time zone, so I just wanted to confirm if it is correct or not, or there are gotchas I didn't take care of.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// Assuming we want to get the current time in GMT.
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
cal.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis()
                    + tz.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis())
                    - TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));

// Calendar should now be in GMT.
```

Is the above correct at all?  I did my own test and it seemed to be working as expected, but just wanted to confirm it again with the experts in Stack Overflow.

Comment: What exactly do you need it for?

Basically the timeInMillis value inside Calendar is always since Epoch in GMT, so usually there is no need to do calculation with timeInMillis and GMT offset.

If you need to get the value (like date or time using Calender.get()) in specific TimeZone, you just set the TimeZone through calendar.setTimeZone() and then get the value which will be specific to that timezone.

If for display purposes only, you can set the TimeZone directly on DateFormat also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you simply do a `Calendar.getInstance` with the TimeZone argument, the calendar's internal state for the `get()` methods will return you the field with the time for that timezone.  For example:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    // if i run this at 9 EST this will print 2
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
```

If you just need the local time for display purposes, you can set the `TimeZone` on your format object.  For example:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Like Macarse said though, Joda time is where it's at if you need to do anything more complex.  The Java date APIs are a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer using joda-time instead of that.

Check [this link](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#TimeZones).

Comment: Sure, I have heard of many great things about joda-time, but I am currently restricted to whatever is provided in by Sun's Java.  But thanks anyway, I will definitely give it a shot in the near future.